# Python-No such file or directory getAttribute.js

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I had a Python selenium program working a week or so ago. Now selenium fails on the import:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

The IDLE ouput:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\testpack.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\testpack.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 35, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .webelement import WebElement
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 43, in <module>
    getAttribute_js = pkgutil.get_data(_pkg, 'getAttribute.js').decode('utf8')
  File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\pkgutil.py", line 634, in get_data
    return loader.get_data(resource_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 832, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
>>>
```

When I try to reinstall the package with pip, I am told that the requirements are satisfied.

chromedriver.exe is in c:\Windows\system32.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try first uninstalling, `pip uninstall selenium`, and then reinstall.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ   did the trick!  but weird to see files corrupted. Thinking of upgrading my laptop now.

Answer (score 2):

The error does gives us some hint on whats wrong happening as follows :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
```

Which essentially means *getAttribute.js* wasn't found in it's intended location.

### getAttribute.js

*`getAttribute.js`* file internally works with the *errors* and other critical *JavaScript functions* as below :

- element not selectable
- element not visible
- invalid cookie domain
- invalid element coordinates
- invalid element state
- invalid selector
- invalid selector
- parseInt()
- push()
- indexOf()
- toUpperCase()
- execScript()
- etc

A typical **`getAttribute.js`** file looks like :

```
function(){return function(){var d=this;function f(a){return"string"==typeof a};function h(a,b){this.code=a;this.a=l[a]||m;this.message=b||"";a=this.a.replace(/((?:^|\s+)[a-z])/g,function(a){return a.toUpperCase().replace(/^[\s\xa0]+/g,"")});b=a.length-5;if(0>b||a.indexOf("Error",b)!=b)a+="Error";this.name=a;a=Error(this.message);a.name=this.name;this.stack=a.stack||""}
(function(){var a=Error;function b(){}b.prototype=a.prototype;h.b=a.prototype;h.prototype=new b;h.prototype.constructor=h;h.a=function(b,c,g){for(var e=Array(arguments.length-2),k=2;k<arguments.length;k++)e[k-2]=arguments[k];return a.prototype[c].apply(b,e)}})();var m="unknown error",l={15:"element not selectable",11:"element not visible"};l[31]=m;l[30]=m;l[24]="invalid cookie domain";l[29]="invalid element coordinates";l[12]="invalid element state";l[32]="invalid selector";l[51]="invalid selector";
l[52]="invalid selector";l[17]="javascript error";l[405]="unsupported operation";l[34]="move target out of bounds";l[27]="no such alert";l[7]="no such element";l[8]="no such frame";l[23]="no such window";l[28]="script timeout";l[33]="session not created";l[10]="stale element reference";l[21]="timeout";l[25]="unable to set cookie";l[26]="unexpected alert open";l[13]=m;l[9]="unknown command";h.prototype.toString=function(){return this.name+": "+this.message};var n;a:{var p=d.navigator;if(p){var q=p.userAgent;if(q){n=q;break a}}n=""}function r(a){return-1!=n.indexOf(a)};function t(a,b){for(var e=a.length,c=f(a)?a.split(""):a,g=0;g<e;g++)g in c&&b.call(void 0,c[g],g,a)};function v(){return r("iPhone")&&!r("iPod")&&!r("iPad")};function w(){return(r("Chrome")||r("CriOS"))&&!r("Edge")};var x=r("Opera"),y=r("Trident")||r("MSIE"),z=r("Edge"),A=r("Gecko")&&!(-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf("webkit")&&!r("Edge"))&&!(r("Trident")||r("MSIE"))&&!r("Edge"),aa=-1!=n.toLowerCase().indexOf("webkit")&&!r("Edge");function B(){var a=d.document;return a?a.documentMode:void 0}var C;
a:{var D="",E=function(){var a=n;if(A)return/rv\:([^\);]+)(\)|;)/.exec(a);if(z)return/Edge\/([\d\.]+)/.exec(a);if(y)return/\b(?:MSIE|rv)[: ]([^\);]+)(\)|;)/.exec(a);if(aa)return/WebKit\/(\S+)/.exec(a);if(x)return/(?:Version)[ \/]?(\S+)/.exec(a)}();E&&(D=E?E[1]:"");if(y){var F=B();if(null!=F&&F>parseFloat(D)){C=String(F);break a}}C=D}var G;var H=d.document;G=H&&y?B()||("CSS1Compat"==H.compatMode?parseInt(C,10):5):void 0;var ba=r("Firefox"),ca=v()||r("iPod"),da=r("iPad"),I=r("Android")&&!(w()||r("Firefox")||r("Opera")||r("Silk")),ea=w(),J=r("Safari")&&!(w()||r("Coast")||r("Opera")||r("Edge")||r("Silk")||r("Android"))&&!(v()||r("iPad")||r("iPod"));function K(a){return(a=a.exec(n))?a[1]:""}(function(){if(ba)return K(/Firefox\/([0-9.]+)/);if(y||z||x)return C;if(ea)return v()||r("iPad")||r("iPod")?K(/CriOS\/([0-9.]+)/):K(/Chrome\/([0-9.]+)/);if(J&&!(v()||r("iPad")||r("iPod")))return K(/Version\/([0-9.]+)/);if(ca||da){var a=/Version\/(\S+).*Mobile\/(\S+)/.exec(n);if(a)return a[1]+"."+a[2]}else if(I)return(a=K(/Android\s+([0-9.]+)/))?a:K(/Version\/([0-9.]+)/);return""})();var L,M=function(){if(!A)return!1;var a=d.Components;if(!a)return!1;try{if(!a.classes)return!1}catch(g){return!1}var b=a.classes,a=a.interfaces,e=b["@mozilla.org/xpcom/version-comparator;1"].getService(a.nsIVersionComparator),c=b["@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1"].getService(a.nsIXULAppInfo).version;L=function(a){e.compare(c,""+a)};return!0}(),N=y&&!(8<=Number(G)),fa=y&&!(9<=Number(G));I&&M&&L(2.3);I&&M&&L(4);J&&M&&L(6);var ga={SCRIPT:1,STYLE:1,HEAD:1,IFRAME:1,OBJECT:1},O={IMG:" ",BR:"\n"};function P(a,b,e){if(!(a.nodeName in ga))if(3==a.nodeType)e?b.push(String(a.nodeValue).replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,"")):b.push(a.nodeValue);else if(a.nodeName in O)b.push(O[a.nodeName]);else for(a=a.firstChild;a;)P(a,b,e),a=a.nextSibling};function Q(a,b){b=b.toLowerCase();return"style"==b?ha(a.style.cssText):N&&"value"==b&&R(a,"INPUT")?a.value:fa&&!0===a[b]?String(a.getAttribute(b)):(a=a.getAttributeNode(b))&&a.specified?a.value:null}var ia=/[;]+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)(?=(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*$)/;
function ha(a){var b=[];t(a.split(ia),function(a){var c=a.indexOf(":");0<c&&(a=[a.slice(0,c),a.slice(c+1)],2==a.length&&b.push(a[0].toLowerCase(),":",a[1],";"))});b=b.join("");return b=";"==b.charAt(b.length-1)?b:b+";"}function S(a,b){N&&"value"==b&&R(a,"OPTION")&&null===Q(a,"value")?(b=[],P(a,b,!1),a=b.join("")):a=a[b];return a}function R(a,b){b&&"string"!==typeof b&&(b=b.toString());return!!a&&1==a.nodeType&&(!b||a.tagName.toUpperCase()==b)}
function T(a){return R(a,"OPTION")?!0:R(a,"INPUT")?(a=a.type.toLowerCase(),"checkbox"==a||"radio"==a):!1};var ja={"class":"className",readonly:"readOnly"},U="async autofocus autoplay checked compact complete controls declare defaultchecked defaultselected defer disabled draggable ended formnovalidate hidden indeterminate iscontenteditable ismap itemscope loop multiple muted nohref noresize noshade novalidate nowrap open paused pubdate readonly required reversed scoped seamless seeking selected spellcheck truespeed willvalidate".split(" ");function V(a,b){var e=null,c=b.toLowerCase();if("style"==c)return(e=a.style)&&!f(e)&&(e=e.cssText),e;if(("selected"==c||"checked"==c)&&T(a)){if(!T(a))throw new h(15,"Element is not selectable");b="selected";e=a.type&&a.type.toLowerCase();if("checkbox"==e||"radio"==e)b="checked";return S(a,b)?"true":null}var g=R(a,"A");if(R(a,"IMG")&&"src"==c||g&&"href"==c)return(e=Q(a,c))&&(e=S(a,c)),e;if("spellcheck"==c){e=Q(a,c);if(null!==e){if("false"==e.toLowerCase())return"false";if("true"==e.toLowerCase())return"true"}return S(a,
c)+""}g=ja[b]||b;a:if(f(U))c=f(c)&&1==c.length?U.indexOf(c,0):-1;else{for(var u=0;u<U.length;u++)if(u in U&&U[u]===c){c=u;break a}c=-1}if(0<=c)return(e=null!==Q(a,b)||S(a,g))?"true":null;try{var k=S(a,g)}catch(ka){}(c=null==k)||(c=typeof k,c="object"==c&&null!=k||"function"==c);c?e=Q(a,b):e=k;return null!=e?e.toString():null}var W=["_"],X=d;W[0]in X||!X.execScript||X.execScript("var "+W[0]);
for(var Y;W.length&&(Y=W.shift());){var Z;if(Z=!W.length)Z=void 0!==V;Z?X[Y]=V:X[Y]&&X[Y]!==Object.prototype[Y]?X=X[Y]:X=X[Y]={}};; return this._.apply(null,arguments);}.apply({navigator:typeof window!='undefined'?window.navigator:null,document:typeof window!='undefined'?window.document:null}, arguments);}
```

### Error Reason :

Incase the `getAttribute.js` file doesn't gets downloaded properly *Selenium* and *webdriver* modules may not work properly. The issue can arise if the *Selenium Client* encounters any error during its transmission or storage.

*Selenium Team* is currently working on the issue [*SeleniumHQ/selenium/5378*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5378) to generate the binary checksum of the *Downloaded Selenium Client* which will help you to avoid encountering errors which may have been introduced during its transmission or storage.

### Solution

Till then a solution will be to :

- Check if *Python* is properly installed

  ```
  C:\Users\username>python
  Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:69c0db5, Jan 31 2018, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
   on win32
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>>
  ```
- Ensure *pip* is working properly

  ```
  C:\Users\username>pip

  Usage:
    pip <command> [options]

  Commands:
    install                     Install packages.
    download                    Download packages.
    uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
    freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
    list                        List installed packages.
    show                        Show information about installed packages.
    check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
    search                      Search PyPI for packages.
    wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
    hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
    completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
    help                        Show help for commands.

  General Options:
    -h, --help                  Show help.
    --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
    -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
    -V, --version               Show version and exit.
    -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
    --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
    --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
    --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5 times).
    --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
    --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup, (a)bort.
    --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any HTTPS.
    --cert <path>               Path to alternate CA bundle.
    --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private key and the certificate in PEM format.
    --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
    --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
    --disable-pip-version-check
                    Don't periodically check PyPI to determine
                    whether a new version of pip is available for
                download. Implied with --no-index.
  ```
- Uninstall *Selenium* completely through pip

  ```
  C:\Users\username>pip uninstall selenium
  Uninstalling selenium-3.4.2:
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2.dist-info\description.rst
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2.dist-info\installer
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2.dist-info\metadata
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2.dist-info\metadata.json
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2.dist-info\record
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2.dist-info\top_level.txt
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.2.dist-info\wheel
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\__init__.py
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-36.pyc
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\common\__init__.py
    .....
    .....
    .....  
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\events.py
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\ui.py
    c:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py
    c:\python\selenium\webdriver\firefox\amd64\x_ignore_nofocus.so
    c:\python\selenium\webdriver\firefox\x86\x_ignore_nofocus.so
    c:\python\selenium\webdriver\remote\getattribute.js
    c:\python\selenium\webdriver\remote\isdisplayed.js
  Proceed (y/n)? y
    Successfully uninstalled selenium-3.4.2
  ```
- Install the latest *Selenium* through pip

  ```
  C:\Users\username>pip install -U selenium
  Collecting selenium
    Downloading selenium-3.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (931kB)
      100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 942kB 322kB/s
  Installing collected packages: selenium
  Successfully installed selenium-3.9.0
  ```
- Confirm that *Selenium* is installed

  ```
  C:\Users\AtechM_03>pip freeze
  selenium==3.9.0
  ```
- Open an IDE (e.g Eclipse, PyCharm) and write a simple program as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
  driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error when I create the .exe file with Pyinstaller since I upgrade the library.

In my case, the problem occurs because Pyinstaller doesn't include the selenium folder in the output folder. I copy the selenium folder from an another older program and that way it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your webdriver installation files are either corrupted or missing. Reinstall/upgrade the webdriver eggs.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
```

**Try this:**

```
pip install selenium --upgrade
```

Comment: @MikeMathMan it is not. This answer will not really work if the version is already up to date, t believe.

Answer (score 0):

you have to reinstall the selenium- Windows version from here https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files

Seems that the installation was broken. If you want to install from the repo, you need to follow the steps here first in order to build the .js files you need: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Python-Bindings#development

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however I just had this problem and I thought it would be nice to contribute.

In my case, I am using both selenium and PyInstaller (using the `--onefile` option). I had no issues when running the script, but the executable threw the same exception mentioned by OP. My solution was to run PyInstaller as:

```
pyinstaller script.py --onefile --collect-data selenium
```

It ran just fine, untile the point I tried to download a file while interacting with a webpage using selenium. I got a similar error related to missing certificates. I solved the problem by also including the offending file via `--collect-data certify`, *i.e.*,

```
pyinstaller script.py --onefile --collect-data selenium --collect-data certify
```