# Python Selenium Webdriver Error on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

I need some help with the geckodriver. I have installed it on Environment Path on Windows, but still i got this error and i really don't know what to do to fix it.

```
  File "Raport_FR_CH_Nata.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\cursu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\cursu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\cursu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .webelement import WebElement
  File "C:\Users\cursu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 43, in <module>
    getAttribute_js = pkgutil.get_data(_pkg, 'getAttribute.js').decode('utf8')
  File "C:\Users\cursu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\pkgutil.py", line 637, in get_data
    return loader.get_data(resource_name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\cursu\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\selenium-3.141.0-py3.7.egg\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
```

The user is running Windows 10.

Thank you,
I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859312/python-no-such-file-or-directory-getattribute-js) answer only reinstalling is the way.

it quotes

> Incase the getAttribute.js file doesn't gets downloaded properly
>   Selenium and webdriver modules may not work properly. The issue can
>   arise if the Selenium Client encounters any error during its
>   transmission or storage.
>
> Selenium Team is currently working on the issue
>   [SeleniumHQ/selenium/5378](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5378) to generate the binary checksum of the
>   Downloaded Selenium Client which will help you to avoid encountering
>   errors which may have been introduced during its transmission or
>   storage.

Try first uninstalling:

`pip uninstall selenium`

Then install it again:

`pip install selenium --upgrade`

Comment: Thank you! I am installing python modules directly not through pip with python setup.py install. I have a strong firewall and can't use pip as all the ports are closed...Thanks!

Comment: Hi,

I have installed it from here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/Selenium.
Downloaded the zip, unarchieve it and installed it from py folder with python setup.py install.
You can close the ticket as i reinstalled the selenium- Windows version from here and all was fine! https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files

Seems that the installation was broken.

Thank you!

Comment: @Cohen there is no ticket here. But you can mark my answer as accepted that will term it as a `closed with satisfactory answer`