# 163 INFO: UPX is not available. selenium pyinstaller one file.exe

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I 've been reading almost all the posts related to this topic but I can´t find a solution!!!.
My folder path is : C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst

Inside the folder I created a virtual env., I added the chromedriver.exe and my script as it can be seen in the image:

[image]

this is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import  expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by  import By
import time

def resource_path(relative_path):

try:
    import sys
    import os
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = sys._MEIPASS
except Exception:
    base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

try :

url = "https://pinterest.com"
driver_path = "chromedriver.exe"

#Instanciamos la clase de Options para definir ciertas opciones:
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--lang=es") #lenguaje que queremos utilizar
#options.add_argument("--headless") # utilizar un navegador sin cabeza
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")# omite los warnings en la consola

#definimos ntro.webdriver:

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[data-test-id='page-scroll-arrow']")
for button in buttons:
    opacity = button.get_attribute("style").split(";")[0][-1]
    if opacity is '1':
        button.click()
    
time.sleep(3)

texto = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h2.unauth-homepage-signup-title').text
with open('result.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(texto)

driver.close()

except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

I added to the service.py file (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py) : creationflags= CREATE_NO_WINDOW and imported CREATE_NO_ WINDOW from subprocess , like this:

```
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW, DEVNULL

import errno
import os
import subprocess
from platform import system
from subprocess import PIPE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common import utils
```

and :

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file,
                                        stderr=self.log_file,
                                        stdin=PIPE,
                                        creationflags=self.creationflags,
                                        creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

All from this posts :

[hide_chrome_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python/66925771#66925771)

Finally, via terminal I try to create one .exe file :

```
pyinstaller --add-data "chromedriver.exe;." --windowed --onefile prueba_1.py
```

But I got this error :

124 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.7
124 INFO: Python: 3.10.0
147 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
149 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\prueba_1.spec
153 INFO: UPX is not available.
script 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\prueba_1.py' not found

and now my folder is like this:

[image]

If I run the script, afther changes in service.py  I got this message:

```
c:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\prueba_script.py:41: SyntaxWarning: 
"is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if opacity is '1':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\prueba_script.py", line 1, in 
<module>
 from selenium import webdriver
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .service import DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE_PATH, Service
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 20, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common import (service, utils)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data Analytics Arg\py_inst\venv\lib\site- 
  packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 77
    creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Could someone help me please???.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
UPX is not available
```

...implies that pyinstaller can not find *`upx.exe`* to encrypt exe file.

---

### Solution

In order to fix this error you need to download [**upx**](https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/) as per your system configuration. Incase of a 64-bit [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) *OS* you need to download:

[image: upx-for-windows-10.png]

Incase you have downloaded **upx** and saved in *`D:\`* you need to do:

```
pyinstaller main.py --key 123456 -n test -F -w --upx-dir D:\
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! it's working now. The .exe has been created, but when I run the file inside the created folder, this message appears:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\KMSpico\\temp\\_MEI146922\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'

 I've tried this:

[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859312/python-no-such-file-or-directory-getattribute-js)

but I still have the problem... Do u know whay am I doing Wrong???

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Linux, you can `sudo apt install upx-ucl` to install the command line version of the upx application.

And as the selected answer says, you can also get tarball and zip versions of the app fromgithub at https://github.com/upx/upx/releases/.