How to replace the deprecated WebElement.get_attribute() function in Selenium 4.27.0+
On some web pages, due to rendering issues (e.g., hidden element), WebElement.text may not reveal the underlying text whereas WebElement.get_attribute("textContent") will. Therefore I have written the following utility function:
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

def text(e: WebElement) -> str:
    return e.text or e.get_attribute("textContent") or "n/a"

WebElement.get_attribute() is deprecated in Selenium 4.27.0. The recommendation is to use WebElement.get_dom_attribute().
However, this is not a drop-in replacement because WebElement.get_dom_attribute() will only reveal attributes declared in the HTML markup.
How would I achieve the same functionality without WebElement.get_attribute()?

To achieve functionality similar to get_attribute():

Use get_property() for properties like textContent.
Use get_dom_attribute() for explicitly declared HTML attributes.
Combine these approaches with WebElement.text for a comprehensive solution.


I don't understand why you talk about "deprecated"? That usually means it will still work, but might be removed in future versions. I am now using 4.27.1 and get_attribute simply doesn't work at all (due to a missing file getAttribute.js). Is it a bug that this file is missing? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859312/python-no-such-file-or-directory-getattribute-js/79299681#79299681

Further research reveals that I can use WebElement.get_property()
This mean a slight change to the utility function because this function can return any one of str | bool | WebElement | dict.
Therefore, it becomes:
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

def text(e: WebElement) -> str | bool | dict | WebElement:
    return e.text or e.get_property("textContent") or False


Don't forget to come back and accept your own answer so the question isn't left unanswered.

The javadoc for the deprecated method getAttribute(String name) in the Java Selenium jar describes the behaviour as :
   * Get the value of the given attribute of the element. Will return the current value, even if
   * this has been modified after the page has been loaded.
   *
   * <p>More exactly, this method will return the value of the property with the given name, if it
   * exists. If it does not, then the value of the attribute with the given name is returned. If
   * neither exists, null is returned.

Strictly, you may want to implement the functionality as described above for a direct replacement.
The difference between attributes and properties is confusing but it might be worth looking at this
